# Using parallel stream to return fastest supplied value

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a set of suppliers that all suppply the same result but with different (and varying) speed.

I want an elegant way to start off the suppliers at the same time and as soon as one of them has produced a value, return it (discarding the other results).

I've tried using parallel streams and the `Stream.findAny()` for this but it always seems to block until all results have been produced.

Here's a unit test demonstrating my problem:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RaceTest {

    @Test
    public void testRace() {
        // Set up suppliers
        Set<Supplier<String>> suppliers = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        suppliers.add(() -> "fast"); // This supplier returns immediately
        suppliers.add(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
                return "slow";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }); // This supplier takes 10 seconds to produce a value

        Stream<Supplier<String>> stream = suppliers.parallelStream();
        assertTrue(stream.isParallel()); // Stream can work in parallel
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Optional<String> winner = stream
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .findAny();
        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        assertTrue(winner.isPresent()); // Some value was produced
        assertEquals("fast", winner.get()); // The value is "fast"
        assertTrue(duration < 9_000); // The whole process took less than 9 seconds
    }
}
```

The result of the test is that the last assertion fails as the whole test takes about 10 seconds to complete.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I just tested your code and it doesn't fail (JDK 1.8.0_51 here). But `findAny` is nondeterministic so it's just luck.

Comment: If you add the fast suppliers 4 times (set size = 5), it works as expected, I suspect that when the stream is too small, it reverts to a sequential execution.

Comment: There is no need for the source to be a `Concurrent…` collection here. Any collection will do, as long as you don’t modify it during the operation. In fact, due to the way it works internally, an ordinary collection performs better at this task, even when it comes to parallel execution. But as already said by others, the `Stream` API is not the right tool here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, you are better off using `Callable` instead of `Supplier` (same functional signature) and use the good old concurrency API that exists since Java 5:

```
Set<Callable<String>> suppliers=new HashSet<>();
suppliers.add(() -> "fast"); // This supplier returns immediately
suppliers.add(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
        return "slow";
    }
);

ExecutorService es=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
try {

    String result = es.invokeAny(suppliers);
    System.out.println(result);

} catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
es.shutdown();
```

Note, how the entire “run all and return the fastest” becomes a single method invocation…

It also has the bonus of canceling/ interrupting all pending operations, as soon as one result is available, so the slow operation won’t actually wait the full ten seconds here (well, in most cases, as the timing is not deterministic).

Comment: The Javadoc of `invokeAny` says "Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully". Does this implies that the one returned is always the first task that has completed (and not another one)?

Comment: @Tunaki: the `interface` can’t specify such a guaranty as it depends on the logic of the actual executor implementation, whether this is the case. E.g., in case of a thread pool executor, you must ensure that it has either no limit on the thread number or at least as much free threads as tasks are available for this to work as intended. The executor returned by `newCachedThreadPool()` has no limit. But while returning the fastest is the obvious intention of `invokeAny`, if you want to put it as formal as possible, there is never such a guaranty when it comes to concurrency…

Comment: This worked perfectly, and also handles failed tasks just like I intended (throw exception only if no task is successful)

Answer (score 4):

The code you are currently using is nondeterministic. Quoting the Javadoc of [`findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic; it is free to select any element in the stream.

You could use a [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) and submit all the tasks to it. Then, [`CompletionService.take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html#take--) will return the `Future` of the first completed task.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(suppliers.size());
CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
suppliers.forEach(s -> completionService.submit(() -> s.get()));
String winner = completionService.take().get();
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
assertEquals("fast", winner); // The value is "fast"
assertTrue(duration < 9_000); // The whole process took less than 9 seconds
```

Comment: This is IMHO much more deterministic and idiomatic than the currently accepted answer. Or to state it that way: *This is exactly what `CompletionService` is for!*

Answer (score 2):

Stream API is not suitable for such things as it does not guarantee when tasks are finished. The better solution would be to use `CompletableFuture`:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
String winner = CompletableFuture
        .anyOf(suppliers.stream().map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync)
                .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join().toString();
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
assertEquals("fast", winner); // The value is "fast"
assertTrue(duration < 9_000); // The whole process took less than 9 seconds
```

Note that it still may not launch all the suppliers in parallel if common FJP has not enough parallelism level. To fix this you can create your own pool which has the required parallelism level:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool(suppliers.size());
String winner = CompletableFuture
        .anyOf(suppliers.stream().map(s -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(s, fjp))
                .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join().toString();
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
assertEquals("fast", winner); // The value is "fast"
assertTrue(duration < 9_000); // The whole process took less than 9 seconds
fjp.shutdownNow();
```